# Python 3 to_bytes function shows wrong result

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, bytestream

I'm trying use the `to_bytes` function. In most cases it works good for me but not always. For example:

```
byteData = (212168254).to_bytes(4,'big')
print (byteData)
```

print should give me `b'\x0c\xa5\x6e\x3e'` but it gives me `b'\x0c\xa5n>'`. Why is that?

Comment: No - that's correct. `6e` and `3e` are printable characters that can be displayed as "n" and ">" - so Python displays them as such.

Comment: If you want hex escapes for everything, do your own hex encoding.

Comment: but still it doesn't looks like lenght of bytes is 4 :)

Comment: @Fuk one thing is the lenght and another completly is the representation, python only "shows" them as `n` and `>` for the print function